# What is the preferred way to present scores based on different combinations of variables?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, stepwise-regression

I have a machine learning model that takes 12 variables as input. I train the model, test it on a validation set, and measure $R^2$.

I have determined that a subset of the variables can be dropped with no significant decrease in $R^2$. Now my advisor has asked me to train the model with all possible combinations of these 12 variables. There are 4096 such combinations.

What is the best way to show the performances of all of these combinations?